# $.jgrid.stripHtml is not a function error...!

Tags: jquery-ui

```
   In my application i am using jqgrid to create the table , but sometimes it works fine &  sometime not..showing $.jgrid.stripHtml is not a function .its very strange kind of situation here which i am not able to understand where i am wrong.
```

// I am using jquery 1.3 plugin for ui devlopement
  please give me any solution to get rid from this problem
       thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this post? You need to load the language file before the jqgrid script.

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/tabletogrid-error-striphtml-is-not-a-function